# Python is ignoring "If (Variable) is not:"

Tags: python

```
if AMPM is not "AM" or AMPM is not "PM":
    AMPM = input('You entered an incorrect value for AMPM. Please, try again: ')
```

It just completely ignores the "Is not" part. I've tried doing != and I get the same result, where it just continues the if statement. Am I doing something wrong?

the complete code: https://pastebin.com/t6WmqPTr

Comment: `!=` is what you want. If that's not working, your example isn't representative.

Comment: If they enter `AM`, that's not `PM`, and if they enter `PM`, that's not `AM`.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

Comment: The statement will always evaluate to `False`.  As @user2357112 mentioned, one of the two statements will always evaluate to `False`, hence the whole statement will as well.

Answer (score 3):

The expression is incorrect outright, but I would recommend a more idiomatic approach anyway:

```
if AMPM not in ('AM', 'PM'):
    # statement
```

This way, you're guaranteed that you'll get the right result if `AMPM` happens to be set to "foo".

Comment: I'd also recommend `tolower`'ing the input and checking only `in ('am', 'pm')`.

Comment: It could also be written as `if re.match('AM|PM', AMPM, re.IGNORECASE) is None:`.

Comment: @DanD.: I did say this was idiomatic. There's really no value in bringing out regex here.

Answer (score 0):

Because AMPM cannot be both "AM" and "PM", the input statement will always be run. You should use `and` instead of `or`. Also, you should use `!=` rather than `is not`. Although `is not` will work in some cases due to string interning.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Rundown:

It saw that AMPM was am, so thats ok. Then it saw AMPM wasn't PM, so it continued. This is my solution:

```
if AMPM != "AM":
  if AMPM != "PM":
    AMPM = input('You entered an incorrect value for AMPM. Please, try again: ')
```

Comment: Typed it wrong. Just pretend there's an indent there, and ill edit it

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your full code, you have the following:

```
if AMPM == "Am" or AMPM == "am":
    AMPM = "AM"
if AMPM == "Pm" or AMPM == "pm":
    AMPM = "PM"

if AMPM is not "AM" or AMPM is not "PM":
    AMPM = input('You entered an incorrect value for AMPM. Please, try again: ')
```

You already checked everything you need above! The part you asked about is what you want to perform when all else fails. This is what the `else` clause is for. So you can fix the code (and make it more clean and readable) like this:

```
if AMPM == "Am" or AMPM == "am":
    AMPM = "AM"

elif AMPM == "Pm" or AMPM == "pm":
    AMPM = "PM"

else:
    AMPM = input('You entered an incorrect value for AMPM. Please, try again: ')
```

In case this is new - `elif` means 'else-if'. If the first `if` is evaluated to false, the program checks the next `elif` after it. If all clauses are false, the `else` section is executed.